# Scrolling with multiple SVGs

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create 4 svg based charts one below another.

After charts are loaded, I can see only 2 and half charts which get occupied on web browser without scrolling. 
I can see scroll bars enabled in left and at the bottom but they don't scroll much.

```
<div overflow="auto">
    <svg id="chart1" style="overflow-y:scroll"></svg>
    <svg id="chart2" style="overflow-y:scroll"></svg>
    <svg id="chart3" style="overflow-y:scroll"></svg>
    <svg id="chart4" style="overflow-y:scroll"></svg>
</div>
```

Above are 4 svg and below is the css for each of them.

```
   #chart1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

When I minimize the webpage, I can see 4 charts otherwise 2 and half only.

What all I have tried:
1. enabling auto-scroll for html, body 
2. enabling scroll in svg (similar to above code).
3. increasing html and body height and width.

```
 html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 200%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
```

Comment: I would recommend putting this into a codepen or a jsfiddle in order for us to test the code in-situ, otherwise it makes it difficult to determine what the problem is

Comment: Remove position:absolute, use one class and use it on chart1, chart2, etc...and avoid css on specific id

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example on jsfiddle, each svg has a data-no, and one common class. It is more easy with this example  for you to explain what you expect exactly...

https://jsfiddle.net/ericsm/ondtxmp2/

and here the code too : 
each svg take 100% of body.

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
    .container-charts {
     border:solid 8px blue;  
     div : 100%;
    }

    .chart {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border:dashed 2px green;
     }

     html, body {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <div class="container-charts" overflow="auto">

    <svg class="chart" data-no="1">
          <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />
        </svg>

        <svg class="chart" data-no="2">
          <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:blue;stroke-width:2" />
        </svg>    

        <svg class="chart" data-no="3">
          <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:gray;stroke-width:2" />
        </svg>

        <svg class="chart" data-no="3">
          <ellipse cx="100" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:black;stroke-width:2" />
        </svg>    

    </div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```